# Trouble reading data with MongoDB in Rust - Unable to iterate and use try_next

Tags: mongodb, rust

I need some help reading data with MongoDB in Rust. I have a collection using a very simple model:

```rs
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct Score {
    pub address: FieldElement,
    pub score: f32,
    pub cheat: bool,
    pub ip_addr : IpAddr,
}
```

I have no issues with writing data, it works great. However, reading data is a nightmare, I can't seem to iterate properly. In the documentation, they suggest doing something like this:

```rs
while let Some(toto) = cursor.try_next().await? {
    println!("score: {}", toto.score);
}
```

The problem is that I get an error message like this:

```
no method named `try_next` found for struct `mongodb::Cursor` in the current scope
items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
```

From what I've read online, the error implies that I'm not implementing the correct traits in my model, specifically `DeserializeOwned`, `Unpin`, `Send`, and `Sync`. But I have no idea how to include these traits, I am new to rust. It seems too strange that it should be so complicated. I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The key sentence in your error message is `items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope`, it tells you that Rust found a method by that name in the `TryStreamExt` trait, but to avoid confusion and a big compile time overhead a traits methods are only considered if the trait is in scope of the current context. You can bring external traits into scope by using a `use` statement in the file where you try to use `try_next`:

```rust
use futures::stream::TryStreamExt;
```

If you dont need the trait other than it's methods you can avoid polluting your namespace by importing and renaming to the special `_`:

```rust
use futures::stream::TryStreamExt as _;
```

You possibly have to add `futures` to your dependencies to be able to import from it.

Comment: Thank you very much. How did you find that import? Vscode suggested me ``use futures_util::stream::try_stream::TryStreamExt;`` which is private and I couldn't find it on the docs.

Comment: It should be in the truncated part of the error message, it's also in the first example of the [docs on `Cursor`](https://docs.rs/mongodb/2.4.0/mongodb/struct.Cursor.html)